# Recibir notificación con app cerrada

Tags: ionic3, push-notification, notificaciones, push

En la aplicación que estoy desarrollando con Ionic 3, quiero implementar el recibo de notificaciones desde Firebase.

Para esto, he instalado el siguiente plugin: cordova-plugin-firebase
He configurado mi proyecto en la consola de Firebase y he añadido el fichero google-services.json.

Una vez hecho esto, pongo el siguiente código en mi archivo app.component.ts:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  firebase.getToken().then(token => {
    alert("Token: " + token);

    firebase.subscribe("probandoAPPRS").then(data => {
      alert("Suscrito al tema probandoAPPRS");

    }).catch(err => {
      alert("Error al suscribirnos al tema probandoAPPRS");  /me suscribo a un tema para probar
    });

    firebase.onNotificationOpen()  //Este método no se ejecuta si la app está cerrada, si está abierta en primer o segundo plano si que lo ejecuta
      .subscribe(data=>{

        localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1,
          title: "Título de not",
          text: "Texto de not",
        });

      }, err=> {

        localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1,
          title: "Título de not Error",
          text: "Texto de not Error",
        });

      });

  }).catch(err=> {

    alert("Error: " + err);

  });

  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

});
```

Como estoy en pruebas me da igual lo que me manden, siempre que me llegue algo, generaré en local una notificación.

Mi problema es el siguiente: si estoy con la app abierta (sea en primer o segundo plano) recibo los datos y genero la notificación en el método onNotificationOpen pero si la app está cerrada no pasa por ese método y no me genera la notificación.

Cuando envío la notificación desde la consola de Firebase me genera una notificación sin yo poder gestionarla (cuando la app está cerrada) aunque no me interesa hacerlo así, yo lo hago de la siguiente manera desde una aplicación hecha en c#:

```
var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + "...");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id=..."));
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"to\": \"/topics/probandoAPPRS\",\"data\": {\"estado\": \"NORMAL\",\"idgrupo\": 0,\"idpropio\": 50,}}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Hola, por lo que entiendo con tu aplicación hecha en c# tu envías las notificaciones, ahora una pregunta, estas notificaciones enviadas desde tu aplicación en c# llegan a tu dispositivo o solo llegan las notificaciones enviadas desde la consola de Firebase?

Comment: Hola Sergio López. La aplicación desde la que envío si, es C#. Si envío desde la consola, llegan sin problema pero con la app cerrada no las puedo gestionar. Desde mi aplicación en c# envío un mensaje de datos, con lo cual con la app cerrada no llega, llega cuando está abierta o cuando la abro

Comment: ¿Estas generando dos notificaciones?, ¿la que te llega de Firebase y aparte una notificación local?

Comment: En parte si, me explico. Desde mi servicio en c#, envío mensajes (o notificaciones, no se como decirlo para que no haya confusiones) a mi aplicación en ionic. Yo capturo ese "mensaje" y decido si tengo o no que crear una notificación en local (en algunos casos la creo y en otros no, depende de la situación).

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es gestionar los datos de la notificación en el método 'firebase.onNotificationOpen()' cuando la app esta cerrada?

Comment: si, o si es en otro método pues en otro porque, si no me equivoco, ese método no es el que "salta" cuando llega una notificación con la app cerrada.

Comment: Ese método en dos ocasiones. 1.- Cuando la app esta cerrada y el usuario abre la notificación. 2.- Cuando la app esta abierta y llega la notificación(en este caso no se mostrará la notificación y como lo dice la documentación es tarea del desarollador informar al usuario [documentación](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/API.md)).

Comment: Eso es cuando la app está en segundo plano (foreground), no cerrada completamente

Comment: Hola yo uso cordova-plugin-fcm [ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm ] y la notificación llega cuando la App está cerrada, pruebala a ver si te resulta.

Comment: Lo que creo que entendí es que no quieres que la app vaya a modo sleep para poder recibir las notificaciones. Bueno puedes usar un plugin de ionic para eso. Busca [aqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode)!

Answer (score 0):

En apps java/kotlin te cuento como se hace esto que queres, por ahi te sirve como para encontrar lo que buscas en tu plataforma.

Tenes que registrar un servicio que corre cuando tu app esta en background para recibir las notificaciones.

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Espero te sirva mi respuesta para que encuentres lo que estas buscando

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No entendí mucho tu idea pero si lo que quieres es realizar puch notificaciones, en ionic no se como hacerlo directamente con firebase, pero tenes la opción de agregar OneSignal es casi lo mismo y de echo esta en la documentación de Ionic Native: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/onesignal/

capas te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas recibir las notificaciones de firebase cloud messaging con la aplicación cerrada debes también enviar el parámetro "notification" en el JSON que envías a firebase.

Existen 2 tipos de mensajes que puedes enviar al cliente con firebase, los mensajes de datos y los mensajes de notificación.

Los mensajes de datos son los datos que llegan a tu función onNotificacionOpen, de esta manera puedes utilizar los parámetros que estas enviando en tu json como "estado“," "idgrupo" y "idpropio".

Con el plugin cordova-plugin-firebase de apache cordova, las notificaciones en foreground es decir cuando la aplicación está en primer plano no despliegan la notificación por si solas, y directamente se ejecuta tu función onNotificationOpen.

Si la aplicación esta en background es necesario enviar un mensaje de notificación, esta desplegará una notificación en tu aplicación, y cuando el usuario haga clic en la notificación, se ejecutará tu función onNotificacionOpen al abrirse la aplicación.

Si configuras en tu JSON el parámetro de "data", te servirá para poder manejar datos en tu función onNotificationOpen.

Si configuras en tu JSON el parámetro "notification", te permitirá mostrar una notificación en el dispositivo.

Tu JSON debería quedar como esto:

```
  {
    "to" :"topics/probandoAPPRS",
    "data": {
       "estado": "NORMAL", 
       "idgrupo" :0,
       "idpropio": 50
    }, 
    "notification":{
       "title":"Mensaje de prueba",
       "body":"Cuerpo del mensaje de prueba"
    }
  }
```

Igual esto es una notificación básica, hay más parámetros que puedes configurar al utilizar FCM, dejo la documentación de firebase cloud messaging ahí se detalla más cada tipo de mensaje.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.